# Update another location onUpdate with firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to keep some data consistent with firebase cloud functions. When data changes in the main list, I want all the data to change in the user's favourite list.

Currently, I am able to call the function and get a log of the correct data which is changing, but my query doesn't work. I am getting the following error:

**TypeError: ref.update is not a function
    at exports.itemUpdate.functions.database.ref.onUpdate**

Here is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.itemUpdate = functions.database
  .ref('/items/{itemId}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {

  const before = change.before.val();  // DataSnapshot after the change
  const after = change.after.val();  // DataSnapshot after the change

  console.log(after);

  if (before.effects === after.effects) {
    console.log('effects didnt change')
    return null;
  }
  const ref = admin.database().ref('users')
    .orderByChild('likedItems')
    .equalTo(before.title);

  console.log(ref);

  return ref.update(after);
});
```

I'm not to sure where I am going wrong, I appreciate all the help and guidance to resolve this!

Cheers.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40592759, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45059154,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45047781, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42105112

Answer (score 1):

[`equalTo()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#equalTo) returns a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Query) object.  You're then trying to call `update()` on that object.  Note that in the linked API docs, Query doesn't have an update() method.  You can't simply "update" a Query that hasn't been performed.  You're going to have to actually perform the query using [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Query#once), iterate the results form the snapshot in the returned promise, and perform further updates using the data you find.